# What is the memory node in kzalloc_node in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, dynamic-memory-allocation

I do not understand what the memory node is in the kzalloc_node function. The description says, "allocate zeroed memory from a particular memory node." But what is a memory node? I am specifically looking at a portion of the deadline I/O scheduler (shown below).

```
static int deadline_init_queue(struct request_queue *q, struct elevator_type *e)
{
    struct deadline_data *dd;

    ...

    dd = kzalloc_node(sizeof(*dd), GFP_KERNEL, q->node);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very good description here:

> https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html
>
> ...the function alloc_pages() calls numa_node_id() to return the
>   logical ID of the node associated with the current running CPU. This
>   NID is passed to _alloc_pages() which calls NODE_DATA() with the NID
>   as a parameter.
>
> On UMA architectures, this will unconditionally result
>   in contig_page_data being returned but NUMA architectures instead set
>   up an array which NODE_DATA() uses NID as an offset into. In other
>   words, architectures are responsible for setting up a CPU ID to NUMA
>   memory node mapping.
>
> This is effectively still a node-local allocation
>   policy as is used in 2.4 but it is a lot more clearly defined.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access

Comment: So in the deadline scheduler situation, the dd pointer is allocated in the same node as the request_queue, correct?

Comment: I was focused on the question "what is a node?".  But I believe the answer is "yes - you are correct".